# Data doesn't transfer to PHP from Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to pass data that comes from a prompt, but the PHP doesn't receive the data.

```
<script>
function test(){
  var  r=prompt("blaksasda");
  if(r){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: {
                param:r,
            }
  });} };
</script>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
echo "$_POST['param']";
?>
```

Comment: Nice url keep it going.

Comment: How would you know? You are not doing anything with the response, you need a success handler or something similar. And you have a typo in your php script.

Comment: Actually @jeroen you can see the POST in chrome developer tools.

Comment: Also, your echo seems wrong. There is a _Parse Error_ in it...

Comment: @Daan Of course, I was just guessing as to the OP's problem ;-)

Comment: @bcesars what is the Parse Error? Please help. Thanks

Comment: @PangApel. Since you put your `$_POST` inside a **double quotes** when echo it, you don't need to include single quotes inside of it. Just change this line to: `echo "$_POST[param]";`  **or** just remove these _double quotes_ `echo $_POST['param'];`.

Comment: I also tried that. Still not working.

Comment: @bcesars the OP could also wrap arrays in brackets `{}` - `echo "{$_POST['param']}";`

Comment: Yes. This is another good option too...

Comment: On a more serious note: What is happening in the console? That should show you *if* an ajax call was made and what the exact response is.

Comment: Are you saying your problem was resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure PHP doesn't receive the data? Probably Ajax call works correctly. The problem is that you don't handle the echoed result.
Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: {param: r}
}).done(function(result) {
  alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the prompt is not showing now.

Comment: Prompt showed.  But the data is still not there.

Comment: The console shows this now. Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: In your `.done(function() { alert(data) });` you're supposed to pass the result coming from your PHP file as a parameter to your function which would look like this`.done(function(result) { alert(result) });`. Try that. That will work. Thanks!

Comment: @kuket15 No worries. Small mistake, happens to everyone. :)

Comment: @sulavvr I'm sorry, but the prompt doesn't show again.

Comment: Ok, so are you getting any error? Add a fail handler to your code `.fail(function(result){ alert('fail:' + result) });` right after the done handler. Make sure the alert you're getting is not being rejected. Try that and see if you're getting the fail alert.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me add the whole thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function test(){
            var r=prompt("blaksasda");
            if(r){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: { param: r }
                }).done(function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }).fail(function(result){
                    alert('failed: ' + result); 
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test()">Click me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

`test.php` looks like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['param'])) {
    echo $_POST['param'];
} else {
    echo 'Whoops';
}
```

So when I click on the button 'Click Me', it's going to call the test function and give you a prompt and you type the text in and when you submit, you get the result back from `test.php`. I tried it and it worked fine.

UPDATE:

Instead of doing an alert in the `success` handler, just set the result like this:

```
.done(function(result){
    $('#result').html(result);
});
```

Your page will look something like this. Whatever you get from your page, your span will have that. Hope it makes sense.

```
<body>
    <button onclick="test()">Click me!</button>
    <br/>
    Prompt result: <span id="result"></span>

</body>
```

Comment: It's working now. Thanks @sulavvr. But is it possible that I will output the data at the page and not on the prompt? Thanks.

Comment: Check the UPDATE, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! One last thing. Can the message prompt be shown on the php page? Thanks a lot @sulavvr!